# How to capture on load event of a page on click of a button in extjs?

Tags: extjs

In my application I have defined different routes. On page 1, I have a button on click of which I have to load page 2 and populate some of its fields.

I have loaded the page on click of the button, but I'm unable to get the reference of that page to do the manipulations.

Is it possible in Ext JS to capture the load event ? Secondly, if this is possible then is there any way to send some parameters from page 1 to page 2 ?

View:

```
{
        xtype : 'button',
        text : 'Button 1',
        handler : 'loadPage'
 }
```

Controller:

```
loadPage: function() {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want change site and send parameters you can do this via url query string.

Example:

```
loadPage: function() {
    window.location.href = "http://example.com/over/there?field1=value1&field2=value2...";
}
```

In loaded page you can read the parameters like:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var c = url.searchParams.get("field1");
console.log(c);
```